# Can't get JSON response on Laravel 6

Tags: php, json, ajax, laravel

So I'm using an ajax request to get data from a php endpoint, as base I used a code I'm using on a login form which also returns data and that one is working so I'm a bit puzzled by this.

This is the JS:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: {
        ws: ws,
        productor: productor,
        product: product
    },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log( response ); // <-- sayd "undefined" on console
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.error( lang["WS.error"] );
    }
});
```

Laravel PHP:

```
class PMWSjs extends Controller
{
    private $PMWShandler;
    private $parameters;

    public function getData (Request $request)
    {
        $this->PMWShandler = new PMWShandler();

        // Gets sent variables variables
        $this->parameters = $request->all();

        switch ($this->parameters["ws"]) {
            case "getProductVariations":
                $this->getProductVariations();
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public function getProductVariations()
    {
        // we get here but nothing is returned, maybe issue is related to response() ? 
        return response()->json([ 'success' => true , 'data' => 'test' ]);
    }

}
```

I keep getting **"undefined"** since no data is sent back.

The weird thing is as I mentioned I have a very similar code working on a form, I'm sure it's something I'm missing but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT: extra info from questions**

Currently testing under **SUCCESS**, line:
**console.log( response['data']);**

Also tried **console.log(response)** and **console.log(response.data)** and get undefined as well.

URI is excluded from csrf protection

dataType: "json" was removed for previous issues and again a very similar code is working for another feature already.

Under network I get **"this request has no response data available"** which makes sense considering the "undefined" variables

error_reporting is already E_ALL and I'm getting no errors.

**UPDATED CODE WITH A SIMPLIFIED VERSION FOR TESTING, STILL NOT WORKING.**

Comment: `console.log(response)` to see what it contains.

Comment: Which method is being called? `success:` or `error:`? Either one could return `undefined` in your log. Are you including `_token` in your request? Or excluding CSRF protection on that route?

Comment: try to define the `dataType: "json"` and you are also not sending any `csrf token` and using the post method try to check this too.

Comment: Currently testing under SUCCESS the line:
**console.log( response['data']);**
console.log
Also tried console.log(response) and is undefined as well

Comment: Instead of guessing, try watching the request in the network tab of your browser's dev tools to see what is actually being returned

Comment: Under network I get "this request has no response data available" which makes sense considering the "undefined" variables.

Comment: If there is no response data, PHP could be throwing an error before your response line. Try turning on error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see. Your issue seems to be server side, so sharing more of your PHP code may help solve this.

Comment: Are you sure that you are logging `response` out of your if statement? response.data is usually axios syntax

Comment: Added the class code for the php part.

Comment: error_reporting was already E_ALL, getting no server side errors and the array I'm sending is ok.

Comment: Step one is sending back a fixed array of data. Probably you have a server-side error, if your server isn't configured properly to report errors, try checking Laravel logs in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I tried sending a fixed array with just 2 strings, still getting nothing, server is properly configured to display errors and when I force a parsing error it goes through the ERROR side of the ajax request and I get to see the error.

Comment: updated the code above with a simplified version for testing and still getting nothing in the response, really weird.

Answer (score -1):

Ok everybody so I figured it out, there is nothing like pillow talking and rest, so I'm calling another method (getProductVariations) and returning the info there, but the method that was called (getData) was returning nothing.

So captured the second method returned data and return it with the initial method and done.

```
$response = $this->getProductVariations();
return $response;
```

**Thank you all for your time and suggestions**

Comment: Questions that are the result of a typographic error are unlikely to help future visitors and are off-topic. You can simply delete the question instead of answering it.